# To check time value in JSpinnerand set date in JDateChooser accordingly

Tags: java, date, jspinner, jdatechooser

I have two **Jdatechooser**(named as firstdate and lastdate) and **Jspinner**(named as starttime and endtime) in a gui.

The scenario is,

1.if i open gui i will get the current time and set it in endtime and currenttime-1 in starttime(the code is below),

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
Date oneHourBack = cal.getTime();
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(oneHourBack);
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(timeStamp);
starttime.setValue(date);
```

2.For both the Jdatechooser i set the current date.

3.If current time is 00:44:36 (HH:mm:ss), in starttime(**Jspinner**) i have to set 23:44:36, with this i have to
 set the firstdate(**Jdatechooser**) value to previous day date instead of current date.

for this am trying the following way,

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
Date curHr = currentTime.getTime();
String curtime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(curHr);
int timeCheck = Integer.parseInt(curtime);

if(timeCheck > 00 && timeCheck < 01){
 //code to set previous day's  
 date                                       
}
```

is this the way to do it? or is there any better way available? Please help

Comment: Can't you simply use the `oneHourBack` `Date` value as the value for the `lastdate` `JDateChooser`?

Comment: `Calendar` has already rolled the `Date` back by a day...is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `oneHourBack` `Date` value as the value for the `lastdate` `JDateChooser`, as not only has the time been rolled back, but so has the date value, for example...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 44);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 36);

Date startTime = cal.getTime();

cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
Date endTime = cal.getTime();

System.out.println("startTime = " + startTime);
System.out.println("endTime = " + endTime);
```

Outputs...

```
startTime = Thu Feb 06 00:44:36 EST 2014
endTime = Wed Feb 05 23:44:36 EST 2014
```

This is the nice thing about `Calendar`